# Sort an array by remainder of 4

Tags: java, arrays

I have an exercise in which I have to sort an array in the following way:

1. the numbers that divide 4 with no remainder will be the first in the array (e.g 4,8,12,16).
2. the numbers  that divide  4 with remainder of 1 will be the second in the array (1,5,9).
3. the numbers that divide  4 with remainder of 2 will be the third in the array (2,6,10).
4. the numbers that divide 4 with remainder of 3 will be last in the array.

For example, the following array:

```
int []a={1,7,3,2,4,1,8,14}
```

will be:

```
4   8   1   1   2   14  3   7
```

the order within the groups does not matter.

I have found a solution which works on O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

However, it is ugly and moves on the array 3 times. I would want a more elegant solution.

This is my code:

```
    int ptr=a.length-1; int temp=0, i=0;
    while (i<ptr){
        //move 3 remained to the end
        if (a[i] % 4==3){
            temp=a[ptr];
            a[ptr]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
            ptr--;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while (i<ptr){
        if (a[i]%4==2)
        {
            temp=a[ptr];
            a[ptr]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
            ptr--;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while (i<ptr){
        if (a[i]%4==1)
        {
            temp=a[ptr];
            a[ptr]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
            ptr--;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
```

Important to know:

- I don't want time complexity worse than O(n), and space complexity worse than O(1).

Comment: You can't sort in time complexity better than `O(n log(n))` without resorting to algorithms which require additional constraints, such as [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Radix_sort).

Comment: You only have to sort the array, but the teacher didn't tell you to sort it by hand, right? Then use a simple `Comparator` ;)

Comment: @MattBall: He's actually partitioning into 4 parts, not sorting. So O(n) is possible.

Comment: Yep, if you can use extra memory a kind of `bucket sort` is possible, wich is bucket is 0,1,2,3 and then in another loop you concanate the bukcet array :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since O(3 * N) is O(N), you only need to loop through the array three times:

1. Move the elements `e % 4 == 0` to the front, swapping elements along the way;
2. Move the elements `e % 4 == 1` to the front, swapping elements along the way;
3. Move the elements `e % 4 == 2` to the front, swapping elements along the way;

The elements that `e % 4 == 3` will be at the end after this.

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = { 1, 7, 3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 14 , 9};
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = current; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[j] % 4 == i) {
                int b = a[j];
                a[j] = a[current];
                a[current] = b;
                current++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: well, isn't it what I did? but... isn't what I did a bit ugly?

Comment: @Alan Posted sample code. Your idea is close but the implementation might be simpler.

Comment: That is certainly a thing I didn't think, and it's a pitty. a loop instead of duplicating code. Thank you!

Comment: You could optimise this a bit by keeping track of how many elements you've already moved to the front for the given remainder, and only looping past those for the next. I guess basically doing `for (int j = current; ...)` should do the trick.

Comment: @millimoose Nice, missed that, was hacking too fast:)

Comment: And the world's tiniest nitpick: It seems like having both `current` and `begin` is unnecessary.  One of those, initialised to `0` before the outer loop, should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use up more memory. This is not correct, but I will still put it.

```
int modulusLength = 4;
List<Integer> array[] = new List<Integer>[modulusLength];
for(int i = 0; i < modulusLength; i++)
    array[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>;

for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++)
    array[a[i]%modulusLength].put(a[i]);

int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].size; j++)
    {
        a[counter] = array[i].get(j);
        counter++;
    }
```

Horrible and scary, but was fun to write. And it works :)

Comment: Quibble: `modulusLength` should probably be called `divisor` since that's what it is. A modulus is an operator and doesn't really have a length.

Comment: Just adds on to the code being horrifying :) sometimes it is just tempting to write scary code, and my work doesn't allow that, so I use SO for it.

Comment: Eh, this approach is mostly nonscary. Except for the multiline unbraced for.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comparator and make use for the very efficient internal sort algorithm.

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
 public int compare(int a, int b) {
  if(a%4 == b%4) {
   if(a < b) return -1;
   if(a > b) return 1;
   return 0;
  } else {
   if(a%4 < b%4) return -1;
   if(a%4 > b%4) return 1;
   return 0;
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Seeing as the problem is partitioning, not truly sorting, the efficient sorting algorithm is suboptimal ;) And even then it *might* (not necessarily) be faster to partition first and then sort the groups themselves.